# Cumulative Sum for Date Difference

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a database with date variables by row. Each row includes a new admission date for each case. There is a unique id number for each case and repeated admissions are allowed. There is also another category variable. I ordered the database by id and grouping category. Then I subtracted every following admission from the previous one to estimate days between two admissions.
This estimation created NA's for the first admission. I need cumulative sums for consecutive admissions to see the whole range.

A sample data frame is below:

```
  ID      Admission Date       Cat     Date_diff   Admission_Rank
<dbl>         <dttm>           <dbl>   <Period>
1326 2015-06-08 00:00:00         1            NA                1
1466 2017-11-27 00:00:00         1            NA                1
1656 2016-10-06 00:00:00         1            NA                1
1594 2015-04-20 00:00:00         2            NA                1
1347 2013-02-14 00:00:00         1            NA                1
1347 2013-03-18 00:00:00         1  32d 0H 0M 0S                2
1347 2013-04-03 00:00:00         1  16d 0H 0M 0S                3
1347 2013-08-15 00:00:00         1 134d 0H 0M 0S                4
1347 2014-05-16 00:00:00         1 274d 0H 0M 0S                5
1347 2014-05-16 00:00:00         1            0S                6
```

A sample data frame is below:

```
ID        Admission Date       Cat     Date_diff     Admission_Rank       Cum_Sum
1326 2015-06-08 00:00:00         1            NA                  1            NA
1466 2017-11-27 00:00:00         1            NA                  1            NA
1656 2016-10-06 00:00:00         1            NA                  1            NA
1594 2015-04-20 00:00:00         2            NA                  1            NA
1347 2013-02-14 00:00:00         1            NA                  1            NA
1347 2013-03-18 00:00:00         1  32d 0H 0M 0S                  2  32d 0H 0M 0S
1347 2013-04-03 00:00:00         1  16d 0H 0M 0S                  3  48d 0H 0M 0S
1347 2013-08-15 00:00:00         1 134d 0H 0M 0S                  4 172d 0H 0M 0S
1347 2014-05-16 00:00:00         1 274d 0H 0M 0S                  5 446d 0H 0M 0S
1347 2014-05-16 00:00:00         1            0S                  6 446d 0H 0M 0S
```

Comment: 1. Can you include the output of `dput(sample_df)` to your question, to make copy-pasting easy? 2. Have you tried using `cumsum()`?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the difference in formatting of the duration (below in seconds), does this do what you want to do?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~id,     ~admission_date,    ~cat,
1326, "2015-06-08 00:00:00", 1, 
1466, "2017-11-27 00:00:00", 1, 
1656, "2016-10-06 00:00:00", 1, 
1594, "2015-04-20 00:00:00", 2, 
1347, "2013-02-14 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2013-03-18 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2013-04-03 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2013-08-15 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2014-05-16 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2014-05-16 00:00:00", 1) |>
  mutate(id = as.integer(id),
         admission_date = as.POSIXct(admission_date),
         cat = as.integer(cat))

df |>
  group_by(id) |>
  arrange(admission_date) |>
  mutate(date_diff = admission_date - lag(admission_date),
         cum_sum = cumsum(coalesce(date_diff, dseconds(0)))) |>
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>       id admission_date        cat date_diff      cum_sum
#>    <int> <dttm>              <int> <drtn>           <dbl>
#>  1  1347 2013-02-14 00:00:00     1       NA secs        0
#>  2  1347 2013-03-18 00:00:00     1  2761200 secs  2761200
#>  3  1347 2013-04-03 00:00:00     1  1382400 secs  4143600
#>  4  1347 2013-08-15 00:00:00     1 11577600 secs 15721200
#>  5  1347 2014-05-16 00:00:00     1 23673600 secs 39394800
#>  6  1347 2014-05-16 00:00:00     1        0 secs 39394800
#>  7  1594 2015-04-20 00:00:00     2       NA secs        0
#>  8  1326 2015-06-08 00:00:00     1       NA secs        0
#>  9  1656 2016-10-06 00:00:00     1       NA secs        0
#> 10  1466 2017-11-27 00:00:00     1       NA secs        0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And here is a database version (code will vary slightly according to the backend):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

db <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())

df <- tribble(
  ~id,     ~admission_date,    ~cat,
1326, "2015-06-08 00:00:00", 1, 
1466, "2017-11-27 00:00:00", 1, 
1656, "2016-10-06 00:00:00", 1, 
1594, "2015-04-20 00:00:00", 2, 
1347, "2013-02-14 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2013-03-18 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2013-04-03 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2013-08-15 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2014-05-16 00:00:00", 1, 
1347, "2014-05-16 00:00:00", 1) |>
  mutate(id = as.integer(id),
         admission_date = as.POSIXct(admission_date),
         cat = as.integer(cat))
df_db <- copy_to(db, df = df, overwrite = TRUE)

df_db |>
  group_by(id) |>
  window_order(admission_date) |>
  mutate(date_diff = admission_date - lag(admission_date),
         cum_sum = cumsum(coalesce(date_diff, 
                                   seconds(0)))) |>
  ungroup() |>
  compute() |>
  arrange(cum_sum)
#> # Source:     SQL [10 x 5]
#> # Database:   postgres  [iangow@/tmp:5432/iangow]
#> # Ordered by: cum_sum
#>       id admission_date        cat date_diff        cum_sum          
#>    <int> <dttm>              <int> <chr>            <chr>            
#>  1  1326 2015-06-08 04:00:00     1 <NA>             00:00:00         
#>  2  1347 2013-02-14 05:00:00     1 <NA>             00:00:00         
#>  3  1466 2017-11-27 05:00:00     1 <NA>             00:00:00         
#>  4  1594 2015-04-20 04:00:00     2 <NA>             00:00:00         
#>  5  1656 2016-10-06 04:00:00     1 <NA>             00:00:00         
#>  6  1347 2013-03-18 04:00:00     1 31 days 23:00:00 31 days 23:00:00 
#>  7  1347 2013-04-03 04:00:00     1 16 days          47 days 23:00:00 
#>  8  1347 2013-08-15 04:00:00     1 134 days         181 days 23:00:00
#>  9  1347 2014-05-16 04:00:00     1 274 days         455 days 23:00:00
#> 10  1347 2014-05-16 04:00:00     1 00:00:00         455 days 23:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>